# ¿Como comprobar si un string tiene multiples valores?

Tags: java

Buenos noches a todos !

Tengo la siguiente duda y es que estoy probando de comprobar que un string contiene varios valores , es decir la siguiente URL

```
https://www.mismarcadores.com/baloncesto/espana/leb-plata/resultados/
```

Pues me gustaría crear una condición que diga que contenga la palabra baloncesto y resultados , vale ?

Por ahora lo más que he conseguido ha sido comprobar si la url contiene la palabra baloncesto , es decir con un contains.

```
String phrase = "baloncesto";
        String url = "https:://www.mismarcadores.com/baloncesto/espana/leb-plata/resultados/";
        System.out.println(url.contains(phrase));
```

Comment: Algo como `url.contains(palabra1) && url.contains(palabra2)`?

Comment: La cosa está en que puedo pasarle más valores independientemente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con esto debería funcionarte:

```
  String[] phrase = {"baloncesto", "resultado"};
    String url = "https:://www.mismarcadores.com/baloncesto/espana/leb-plata/resultados/";
    boolean contains = true;
    int i = 0;
    while(contains && i < phrase.length)
        contains = url.contains(phrase[i++]);
    System.out.println(contains);
```

Comment: Hola ! Por lo que veo aquí me lo hace correctamente , pero me gustaría que cuando sea verdadero salga la url.

Comment: Puedes hacer lo siguiente sustituir la línea de impresión por `System.out.println(contains ? url : "No contiene las letras")`, o  por `if(contains)`

Comment: `if(contains){System.out.println(url);}`